# Click on image to move to front?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can somebody point me in the right direction so I can create a function like [this?](http://sawyerhollenshead.com/)

I want to create something similar that when you click on an image in a stack of images it brings it to the front.

Can't seem to find the name of it.

Comment: Without examining how it works, my guess is it merely modifies the `z-index` css property.  `$(this).css('z-index', 999);` while simultaneously setting the z-index of all others back to a low value like 0, based on their class or something

Comment: read more on `style.zIndex` property and `click` event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("img.myclass").click(function() {
     $("img.myclass").not(this).css("z-index", 0);
     $(this).css("z-index", 100);
});
```

should help you get started

Answer (score 1):

If the images are positioned with `position: absolute`, you can append an onclick handler to them and change their `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it so you have a global `zIndex` variable and you just update with the latest value + 1.

```
var zIndex = 0;
$('.myImageClass').click(function(){
  zIndex++;  
  $(this).css('zIndex', zIndex);
});
```

z-index only affects elements that are positioned anything other than static (so: relative, absolute or fixed).

Using this method, you would be able to place them in any order you want, instead of always reverting everything else to their defaults.