# How to make the image appear front/back on click using angular1?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-1.5

I would like to implement in such a way that , when we click the image ,the selected image should appear front and the rest of the images should hide behind the selected image .

I have got the code reference of similar functionality achieved using jquery .

[Click on image to move to front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614966/click-on-image-to-move-to-front)

please let me know how this can be done using Angular or using plain javascript?

Comment: Use ng-style to change the z-index of the images to make them come front when you click on them.

Answer (score 3):

Using plain javascript:

```
    let images = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, (img) => img.addEventListener('click', function() {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, (img) => img.style.zIndex = 0);

      this.style.zIndex = 100;
    }));
```

Comment: Glad to help you